# Can you safely delete old entries in sales_flat_quote?

Tags: magento

We have an install that is currently running Magento CE v1.5 (it has been upgraded over time, I think it started on approximately 1.1). The `sales_flat_quote` table currently has upward of 550,000 rows in it. A large percentage of these have a `null` `customer_id` and are many months old. I can't think of a reason to keep them around, since they are old and not associated with a customer there is assumably no way anybody can ever get access to that quote again.

It seems strange that Magento doesn't seem to have a built in functionality for removing what seems like junk information (they do have a cron for removing quotes, but as far as I can tell, it only removes quotes that are set to is_active false, which as far as I can tell only happens when a quote is converted to an order).

Essentially, what I'm asking is...
a.) Is it safe to delete these entries?
b.) What is the best way of doing it (pure sql, via model, some option in the control panel I've missed, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've had several sites that needed the order information cleared after going from dev to production.  We did it by truncating the `sales_flat_*` and several other tables.  We didn't have any problems with it.  However, I recommend testing any direct database edits on a COPY of your database.

You can also delete records from `sales_flat_quote` even if you don't delete the corresponding order records or other tables in `sales_flat_*`.  You should probably only delete records in the quote table that are more than 30 days old though, so that customers will have access to recent carts.

Here is a very helpful post from the Magento Commerce Forums.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1680/P405/

Comment: After running many tests we eventually ended up deleting everything from the sales_flat_quote table of our live site using MySQL (DELETE rather than TRUNCATE). Up to this point we have had no untoward effects.

Comment: If you don't truncate the other sales_flat_* tables then you can end up with some comments in new orders that carry over from the old, especially if you reset the auto_increment id.

Comment: As far as I can tell, all other quote related tables having foreign key contraints where required. Nothing else was reset, I merely removed rows from the tables maintaining any increments.

Comment: Here is the achived version of the dead link above: https://web.archive.org/web/20150228211104/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1680/P405/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this site if you want to delete unwanted quote entry
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53981/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/218244/#t297757

https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_QuoteCleaner

Comment: Archived links: 1) https://web.archive.org/web/20130112102808/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53981 2) https://web.archive.org/web/20150310150211/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/218244#t297757